# Problem with iterating Nested Array output in n8n javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have an API query to a SaaS service, and it outputs a huge number of results, which I iterate over in an [n8n function node](https://n8n.io/) (javascript based). However, some of the results are deeply nested arrays and I'm struggling to get the output working correctly. For single-level nested arrays it's working ok.

I have a massive single JSON input that is coming in such as this (one result of many to show structure):

```
{
"success": true,
"articles": [
    {
        "guid": "aaaa1234",
        "title": "some interesting text here",
        "summary": "some interesting text here.",
        "type": "public",
        "publishedDate": "2021-07-05T07:00:00.000+00:00",
        "link": "https://some_interesting_text_here",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [
            "aab",
            "bb",
            "cc",
            "dd",
            "ee",
            "ff",
            "gg",
            "hh"
        ],
        "indicators": [
            {
                "type": "some interesting text here",
                "count": 4,
                "values": [
                    "some interesting text here",
                    "some interesting text here",
                    "some interesting text here",
                    "some interesting text here"
                ],
                "source": "public"
            }
        ]
    },
```

and the n8n function node that is iterating over the results is as follows (to split them into separate results):

```
const results = []
for (const item of items) {
  results.push.apply(results, item.json.articles)
}

return results.map(element => {
  const json = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(element)) {
    if (key === 'tags') {
      json[key] = element[key].toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
      continue;
    }
    if (key === 'indicators') {
      json[key] = element[key].map(data => data.name).toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
      continue;
    }
    // All others that are not specifically set will fall back to the default logic
    json[key] = typeof element[key] === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(element[key]) : element[key];
  }
  return { json };
})
```

and the output looks like this,

```
    {
"guid": "aaaa1234",
"title": "some interesting text here",
"summary": "some interesting text here",
"type": "public",
"publishedDate": "2021-07-05T07:00:00.000+00:00",
"link": "https://some_interesting_text_here",
"categories": "[]",
"tags": "aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh",
"indicators": " "
},
```

When then exported to a Google Sheet it looks like this(per result):

[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQU9j.png)

How can I get the nested arrays to list correctly? (notice the empty "indicators" results.

Javascript(is what the n8n system uses) isn't my bag so I'm at the level of my javascript troubleshooting here on my own and looking for some help to solve this last hurdle.

Comment: Your "indicators" structure element has no "name" property, so "data.name" will be undefined.  Did you want that values array?

Comment: yes, the values array mostly

Comment: ahh, i see now what you're getting at. By naming it data.values im getting them shown there sort of.

But if I wanted to also parse the rest, can that be done also, just repeated each result by a \n as in the .replace function?

Comment: Take a look at object-scan. It's made for this use case (disclaimer I'm the author)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the "values" from all the "indicators", joined into a list.  So if there are 2 indicators in the array and 4 values in each, you'll get a list of 8 "values".  Might not be ideal, there might be duplicates.

Also take a look at [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - you'll see I use it twice here, it's a better alternative to .toString.replace.

```
json[key] = element[key].map(data => data.values.join("\n")).join("\n");
```